# Open Api 3.0 Swagger application with Visual Studio 19 - database connection problem

Tags: oracle, timeout, database-connection, openapi

I have to make application for .NET5.0.  (Core). I have installed packages Devart.Data (5.0.2658) and Devart.Data.Oracle(9.14.1234).
I use 32 bits oracle client in my computer.
I have switched my application to x86 mode.

I need to connect to a Oracle 12 server.

Here is my code:

```
    [Route("GetMyData")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Cis_titul_pred> GetCiselnik()
    {
        List<DataModule.BO.Cis_titul_pred> testlist = 
        DataModule.DAL.Cis_titul_predDB.Instance.GetList();
        return testlist;
    }

    public  List<Cis_titul_pred> GetList()
    {
        List<Cis_titul_pred> cis_titul_predList = null;
        using (OracleConnection oraConnect = new OracleConnection(AppConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(selectList, oraConnect);
            oraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oraConnect.Open();
                using (OracleDataReader oraReader = oraCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (oraReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        cis_titul_predList = new List<Cis_titul_pred>();
                        while (oraReader.Read())
                        {
                            cis_titul_predList.Add(FillCis_titul_pred(oraReader));
                        }
                    }
                    oraReader.Close();
                }
                oraConnect.Close();
        }
        return cis_titul_predList;
    }
```

When I created  .NET5.0 Desktop (WinForms) application , everything worked properly - I could connect to Oracle server and read data.

When I created  .NET5.0 WEB application , everything worked properly - I could connect to Oracle server and read data.

When I created  .NET5.0 OpenApi application , I got error message "Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException (0x80004005): Server did not respond within the specified timeout interval
at Devart.Data.Oracle.dp.a(cj A_0, di A_1)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(cj connectionOptions, OracleInternalConnection proxyConnection)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.ci.a(ae A_0, Object A_1, DbConnectionBase A_2) Etc. ... Etc..."

I use the same code to connect to the Oracle server in all three applications

I tried change target framewor to NET.Core 3.0, or NET.Cre 3.1, but  without success.

Any ideas?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by  .NET5.0 OpenApi application? It's the same architecture with .net5 web... Please check If you have a correct and same connection string in your appSettings.json file. Also consider using dependancy injection instead of creating `OracleConnection` instance inside controllers

Comment: There are exists: ASP.NET Core Web App,  ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-view-controller) and also ASP.NET Core Web Api.

I have problem with ASP.NET Core Web Api (Open Api 3.1 speciffication with Swagger)